# Cannot downcast UIButton to a subclass

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have searched around and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to downcast a `UIButton` to a subclass in the following line of code:

```
var currentButton: FileButton = UIButton(type: .System) as! FileButton
```

`FileButton` is a simple subclass of `UIButton` that just stores a couple variables with the button. Code is below:

```
import UIKit

class FileButton: UIButton {

     var fileAddress: String = ""
     var fileMsgId: String = ""
     var fileAppId: String = ""

}
```

I am getting the following error in the console when I try to execute this code:

> Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x19e9c9e40) to
>   'CollectionFun.FileButton' (0x100127490).

Any thoughts? This seems like it should be simple but I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply call:

```
var currentButton: FileButton = FileButton(type: .System)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not downcast object in your example. You create `UIButton` type object and try to convert it to other object that not the parrent for it or is higher in the inheritance hierarchy , in this case new object have more functionality and need to allocate more memory for example. You can make your code compiled without error like this:

```
var currentButton = UIButton(type: .System) as? FileButton
```

but it will be useless code, because it will always return `nil`

To explain more clearly give an example. You can do this:

```
var button1 = FileButton()
button1.fileAddress = "qwerty"
var button2 = button1 as UIButton
var button3 = button2 as? FileButton
print(button3.fileAddress)
```

`print` will be

> Optional("qwerty")

And it will be work becoause first object was `FileButton` type.

But this code:

```
var button1 = UIButton()
var button2 = button1 as? FileButton
print(button2?.fileAddress)
```

will print

> nil

And you try to do like second example

Answer (score 0):

Like other object oriented languages, if you initialize a variable as a superclass (in your case `UIButton`) you cannot downcast it to a subclass (in your case `FileButton`). This is because you are initializing a `UIButton` object, which is not a `FileButton`. Simply change your code to initialize a `FileButton` object, and it should work.

You should therefore replace `UIButton(type: .System) as! FileButton` with `FileButton(type: .System)`. Note that the cast is not necessary now, as we are directly initializing a `FileButton` object.

Comment: Thank you (and the other responders). This worked. I didn't know you could use superclass initializers on a subclass.

Comment: If the answer helped you, it would be great if you could mark it as accepted (click the check next to the answer). It would help others with the same question.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the tip - am new to stackoverflow and the UI is still quite confusing.